# Selenium click until the attirbute show

Tags: java, selenium

How can I create click method which can be click in the button until the attribute shows? Something like loop until but with timer (if it's not found attribute after 10 seconds, display an error). I have created something like that, but code give me NullPointerException when not found attribute:

```
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
        String attribute = button.getAttribute("disabled");
        button.click();
        if(attribute .equals("true")) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an initially disabled button and you need to wait less than 10 seconds when this button becomes clickable. Or you have a clickable button that must become disabled after one or more clicks within 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem and my solution was to write a function that tries to click on the object and when it is not present it waits a second and tries once again. After 10 times of trying it returns null.

It works beautifully for me. Goes like this:

```
WebElement tryfind(WebDriver browser, By id)
{
  WebElement ttwel=null;
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    try
    {
      ttwel=browser.findElement(id);
      break;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
    {
      sleep(1000);
    }
  }
  return ttwel;
}

void sleep(int mills)
{
  try
  {
    Thread.sleep(mills);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException ex)
  {
  }
}
```

You might add waiting for disabled attribute to this method, something like:

```
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    try
    {
      ttwel=browser.findElement(id);
      String attribute = button.getAttribute("disabled");
      if (attribute==null) sleep(1000);
      else break;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
    {
      sleep(1000);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a try catch block like this below to catch the NullPointerException and return false in that case

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
      wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
         public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
            try {
               String attribute = button.getAttribute("disabled");
               button.click();
               if (attribute.equals("true")) {
                  return true;
               }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
               return false;
            }
            return false;
         }
      });
```